# how to make data structures persistent in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, persistence

how to make data structures(like trees, graphs  )  persistent in c++?

Comment: What do you mean by 'persistant'?  Do you mean writing it to disk?  Keeping it alive after the function in which it was created exits?  Something else?

Comment: I would have thought it meant an immutable persistent data structure, as in the case of functional languages.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) or the [Boost serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

In general, you will need to serialise the structure so that you can write it to a file or a database. If you have a custom structure, then you will need to write the method to serialise and deserialise (i.e. write out and read in the structure). Otherwise, if you have used a structure from a library, there may already be (de)serialisation methods.

eg. A linked list might serialise as a string like so: `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Answer (score 1):

```
struct S {
  /* ... */
};

//...

ofstream out("temp.aux");

S s;

char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s);
out << sizeof(s);
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(s); ++i) {
  out << c[i];
}
out.close();

// ...

ifstream in("temp.aux");
int size;
in >> size;
char* r = new char[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  in >> r[i];
}
S* s = reinterpret_cast<S*>(r);
in.close();
```

quick and dirty =D